# Re-mapping PgUp and PgDn on PC keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, pc, karabiner

I have a setup where I use the same (PC) keyboard for my **PC** and my **Mac mini** using a switch box. I switch back and forth between the two all the time - and in order to stay sane I have
re-mapped many of the Mac shortcuts/keys using the **Karabiner tool**, so they function as they do on my PC (keys like Cut, Paste, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, etc... ).

But I don't seem to be able to find a mapping in Karabiner that makes <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> work the same way on Mac as it does on PC. When I press <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDn</kbd> on Mac it scrolls the page,
**but don't seem to move the cursor**. Funny enough - if I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd>) + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> it does exactly what I want.

**So basically, how do I get the <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to work as <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to work as <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd>?**

Comment: Isn't it possible to map PgUp to Option+PgUp in Karabiner?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that *should* work (I've got no PC keyboard):

```
{  "description": "page_up & page_down with cursor move",
       "manipulators": [
             {  "conditions": [ 
                { "bundle_identifiers":
                [ "^com.apple.TextEdit", "^com.any.other.app" ],
                  "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                                    } ]
             },
             {  "from": { "key_code": "page_up" },
                "to": [ { "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to key code 116 using option down'" } ],
                "type": "basic"
             },
             {  "from": { "key_code": "page_down" },
                "to": [ { "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to key code 121 using option down'" } ],
                "type": "basic"
             }
] }
```

I am not sure that the "conditions" manipulator is necessary with a PC keyboardºº (test it!).
*IF IT IS* you should add other text processing apps there (identifiable via Karabiner-EventViewer's Frontmost Application tab).

*ºº(On my Apple keyboard "page_xx" otherwise no longer works with e.g. Safari.)*